# How do check for an element in a Map that is in a List

Tags: groovy

I have a List of Maps.  I want to check if any of the Maps contains a specific key value pair.

```
myKey = myValue
```

What is the most Groovy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the method:

```
List findMaps( List<Map> m, Map pattern ) {
    m.findAll { map -> pattern.findAll { k, v -> map[ k ] == v }.size() == pattern.size() }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
def listOfMaps = [ [ a:1, b:2 ], [ a:3, b:4 ], [ a:5, b:2 ] ]

assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ a:3 ] )      == [ [ a:3, b:4 ] ]
assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ a:1, b:2 ] ) == [ [ a:1, b:2 ] ]
assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ b:2 ] )      == [ [ a:1, b:2 ], [ a:5, b:2 ] ]
assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ c:4 ] )      == []
```

There may be shorter ways of doing it...  I'll have a think ;-)

#### Edit:  This is shorter:

```
List findMaps( List<Map> m, Map pattern ) {
    m.findAll { map -> map.subMap( pattern.keySet() ) == pattern }
}
```

;-)

#### shorter still

```
List findMaps( List<Map> m, Map pattern ) {
    m.findAll{ map -> !( pattern - map ) }
}
```

Comment: I did the thinking for you ... ;-)

Comment: @dmahapatro found a shorter method ;-)

Comment: I found the *shortest*. 2 characters shorter that your shorter version :P

Comment: This was too good to optimize. I like and will love to see if you come up with a still shorter and a lucid way.

Comment: @dmahapatro how's that?

Comment: Darnnnnnn. Why didn't I see that? That is awesome.

Comment: Now is the time to drop the verbosity `map`. `m.findAll { !( pattern - it ) }` should be it.

Comment: You excelled the challenge. I owe you a beer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose Tim was looking for this. :)

```
List findMaps( List<Map> m, Map pattern ) {
 m.findAll{map -> map.findResults{map.intersect(pattern) == pattern ? it : null}}
}

def listOfMaps = [ [ a:1, b:2 ], [ a:3, b:4 ], [ a:5, b:2 ] ]

assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ a:3 ] )      == [ [ a:3, b:4 ] ]
assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ a:1, b:2 ] ) == [ [ a:1, b:2 ] ]
assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ b:2 ] )      == [ [ a:1, b:2 ], [ a:5, b:2 ] ]
assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ c:4 ] )      == []
```

If you just need to match any entry  instead of matching the whole map, then you can loosen up the matching of the pattern with the intersection and let Groovy Truth do its job:

```
List findMaps( List<Map> m, Map pattern ) {
    m.findAll{ map -> map.findResults{ map.intersect(pattern) ? it : null } }
}

assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ a:3 ] )      == [ [ a:3, b:4 ] ]
assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ a:1, b:2 ] ) == [ [ a:1, b:2 ], [a:5, b:2] ]
assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ b:2 ] )      == [ [ a:1, b:2 ], [ a:5, b:2 ] ]
assert findMaps( listOfMaps, [ c:4 ] )      == []
```

**Edit: This is shortest:**

```
List findMaps( List<Map> m, Map pattern ) {
    m.findAll { map -> !( pattern - map ).intersect( pattern ) }
}
```

:D

**UPDATE:**
Nice to see Tim coming up even shorter version. I am just copying his idea with little less verbosity and claiming that I have found the shortessssstttttt code yet.

```
List findMaps( List<Map> m, Map pattern ) {
    m.findAll { !( pattern - it ) }
}
```

LOL

Comment: Nice!  I found a shorter method tho ;-)

Comment: i found another shorter one :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
map.each{key, value -> 
    if(key==myKey && value==myValue){
      print key+"="+myValue
    }
}
```