# How to find in a collection?

Tags: groovy

i have the following variable and collection

```
def currentProduct = "ITEM1"
def currentPresentation = "Crema"
def curentMeasure = "1ml"

def items = [[product:"ITEM1", presentation:"Crema", measure:"1ml", quantity:5, total:77.50], [product:"ITEM1", presentation:"Spray", measure:"Habracadabra", quantity:9, total:158.40]]
```

I need to get the quantity value in a map that its product, its presentation and its measure are equal to variable values, hopefully you can help me

Thanks for your time

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: i tried this
list.each { item ->
    if (item.product == "ITEM1" && item.presentation == "Crema" && item.measure == "1ml") {
        println item.quantity
    }
}
and i get the value but i want to find the recomended way to handle this scenarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here You go:

```
items.find { it.product == currentProduct && it.presentation == currentPresentation && it.measure == curentMeasure}?.quantity
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler approach will be as below:

```
def currentProductDetails = [
    product:"ITEM1", presentation:"Crema", measure:"1ml"
]

items.find { !( currentProductDetails - it ) }?.quantity

// in case of multiple products
items.findAll { !( currentProductDetails - it ) }*.quantity
```

You can tailor `currentProductDetails` with whichever key value pair you have in hand for the current product instead of maintaining each variable separately.

Above logic is inspired from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21436256/2051952) which is explained in details in [**this blog**](http://dmahapatro.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-is-groovy-groovy.html).

Comment: Seems complicated at first touch. But nice ;]

Comment: @Opal Yes it looks like, but as it is mentioned in the blog it was very entertaining to drill down to least amount of code which was the objective and the power of higher order functions in Groovy. :)

Comment: Yeah. Definitely yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Dispite good @Opal's answer i will list here some additional possibilities:

- Passing partial item map

  If your item is [product:"ITEM1", presentation:"Crema", measure:"1ml", quantity:5, total:77.50]
  and you want to search by some specified values of item, you can just pass submap of the item.
  e.g.

  ```
  def item = [product:currentProduct, presentation:currentPresentation, measure:curentMeasure]
  def firstQuantity = items.find {it.subMap(item.keySet())==item}.quantity
  ```

  That way allows you to be independent of item's keys.
- Searching all quantities and suming them

  Maybe in some cases you would like to have some of found quantities. You need then to use findAll() method.

  ```
  def all = items.findAll { it.product == currentProduct && it.presentation == currentPresentation && it.measure == curentMeasure}.quantity.sum()
  ```

Comment: nice solution subMap in new to me

Answer (score 0):

Use grep :

```
items.grep{it.product==currentProduct && it.presentation==currentPresentation && it.measure==curentMeasure}.collect{it.quantity}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/3365001)